# How can i build a URL with same key multiple times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm building an iOS app that makes `GET` requests to a URL. For all the requests it makes, I build the url off a base URL and than add parameters using `NSDictionary` Key-Value_pairs.

I also use `AFNetworking 2.0` to make the request - it builds the URL as well, with the NSDictionary keys supplied.

I have now run into a problem, where a web service I need to use, requires multiple keys to be the same, with different values. This functionality is not possible with `NSDictionary`

Which means I cannot run the web service successfully.

Here is an example of what I need the finally URL to look like -

> http://demo.domain.net/services/....*.&IncludedUserIds=12345&IncludedUserIds=2345*

The italic bit of the above URL is what I am trying to build using AFNetworking and NSDictionary. I suspect I will have to use something a little more advanced than NSDictionary to pull this off.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Edit**

Found a half solutions  if I set my NSDictionary Parameters like this with NSSet:

```
    [self.parameters setObject:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"12345",@"2345", nil] forKey:@"IncludedUserIds"];
```

This works as I need it to. However I have a follow up question:

The values need to be dynamically added to NSSet - how do I create an NSSet that can accept extra values at runtime?

Comment: for last part use `NSMutableSet`

Comment: I've used an NSMutableArray instead as I need to be able to remove a certain value - I don't see how that would be easily possible with NSMutableSet as it has no objectAtIndex method. Thanks though!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue:

I just created objects in my NSDictionaray like so:

```
    [self.myDictionary setObject:[NSSet setWithArray:self.myArray] forKey:@"myKeyNeeded];
```

The array has NSString objects in it and this seems to work perfectly. 
I used array instead of `NSMutableSet` due needing to remove objects easily enough from the NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes you can since `&IncludedUserIds=12345&IncludedUserIds=2345` should be the same as `&IncludedUserIds=12345,2345`

So just an array a value for the key in the paramaters dictionary.

Comment: That's the thing - the server doesn't understand comma separated strings. Its treating each "IncludedUserIds" as an array. So IncludedUserIds = 12345,23456 - doesn't exist. But, IncludedUserIds = 12345, IncludedUserIds = 2345 - returns two values that exist.

Comment: Well then you have a real problem using `AFNetworking`, at least using the defaults classes. You will have to roll your own subclass of `AFURLConnectionOperation` which will take `NSArray` as a parameter. That said you server implementation is also not keeping to the HTTP standaard and is the real problem here.

Comment: I have updated my question; I found a sort of solution. Do you know how to solve the last bit? I appreciate your help so far.